# ManagementObjectSearcher not functioning

Tags: vb.net, wmi

```
        Dim cpuWMI As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
    For Each instance As ManagementObject In cpuWMI.Get()
        cpuspeedTXT.Text = instance.GetPropertyValue("CurrentClockSpeed").ToString
    Next
```

I noticed this wasn't working, so I put a breakpoint on `Dim`. When I took one step, it resumed the program (as if it skipped the rest). I also noticed whatever was below this block wouldn't get executed.

Comment: You could insert a temporary line of code after the Dim  and put a breakpoint on that, so you can inspect cpuWMI

Comment: I did do that. I threw in `Dim test` after `cpuWMI`. After stepping past `cpuWMI`, the program resumes. It's completely ignoring anything after `cpuWMI`.

Comment: Dim may not actually generate any IL.  Try inserting Console.WriteLine() instead.  Did the original Dim throw an exception?  That would skip the next line.

Comment: Nope, it didn't throw an exception. It was like everything else after was commented out. `Console.WriteLine()` didn't change anything.

Comment: I think I found it. I put it in a Try/Catch block, and it gave me "Invalid Parameter". Thanks for mentioning exceptions, as that's the only reason I thought to use a Try/Catch block.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the program was simply ignoring my statement was due to a hidden exception. Why it didn't show me the exception, I'm unsure. I put

`Dim cpuWMI As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")`

in a Try/Catch block, and found an "Invalid Parameter" exception. I then realized I don't need the double backslash in `root\\CIMV2`. Removing one backslash solved the issue.

Comment: Breaking on exception is an optional in Visual Studio. See Menu > Debug > Exceptions

Comment: Ah, I was unaware not all exceptions were displayed. That would probably explain a few other bizarre events where code wasn't working, in the past. Perhaps an exception was not shown.